# I am building a website using Bootstrap, I need language support for the search label and pagination

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, globalization

[image]

I am building a website using Bootstrap, I need language support for the search label and pagination, I am unable to render this since there is not direct control, I have the language content in a resource file.

Comment: seems like you are using jquery datatable ?

Comment: If yes then please check it out this link https://datatables.net/reference/option/language